# how to get project_id from analytic account odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have `analytic_account_id` in model `sale_order_line`, how to get `project_id` related from their `analytic_account_id` ? ( i want to add field function `project_id` on `sale_order_line` fill `by project_id` from related `analytic_account_id` ) , i don't know how to do in Odoo-10, help me please...

[image: diagram the relation between project - sale order line - analytic account]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach but can help you:

In `sale.order.line` model define:

```
project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project', compute='compute_project_id')

@api.one
@api.depends('analytic_account_id')
def compute_project_id(self):
    project_id = self.env['project.project'].search([('analytic_account_id', '=', self.analytic_account_id.id)], limit=1)
    self.project_id = project_id and project_id.id or False
```

I hope this can be helpful for you.